# MySQL returns null values for certain rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with MySQL and PHP. I'm trying to create something that gets values from a database, encode it in JSON and then print it. I have that down, but there's something that is keeping from one certain row in the database from displaying. It always returns `NULL` except for the `id` value I set. Here's my code, am I doing something wrong?

```
$srv = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE `name` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']) . "%'");
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($srv)) {
    $playerInfo = array('id' => $playerarray['id'], 'name' => $playerarray['name'], 'server' => $playerarray['server']);
    echo(json_encode($playerInfo));
}
```

If you want to take a look at it, it's hosted [here](http://playersonline.tk/api/search.php?q=geekygamer14&max=31). The funny thing is, [this page](http://playersonline.tk/search.php?q=geekygamer14) uses the exact same code, but doesn't return null. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Here's what is in `$playerInfo` (when I use `geekygamer14`)

```
array (size=3)
  'id' => null
  'name' => null
  'server' => null
```

It seems that whatever rows that have `verified` set to `1` (integer), it gives `NULL`.

Comment: What you have in $playerInfo? var_dump it and post it in the question

Comment: what is $playerarray?, it should be $playerInfo = array('id' => $record['id'], 'name' => $record['name'], 'server' => $record['server']);

Comment: Even the id is null in the results, I think your query doesn't matched any row in the table players

Comment: So where does `$playerarray` come from and what has the while-loop to do with it?

Comment: Found the problem... `$playerarray` was equal to `mysql_fetch_array($srv)`. Whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using variable `$record` in your loop, though this doesn't show in your generated array. Instead you're using a variable named `$playerarray`. I assume the code should be:

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($srv)) {
    $playerInfo = array('id' => $record['id'], 'name' => $record['name'], 'server' => $record['server']);
    echo(json_encode($playerInfo));
}
```

*Note: Consider using an alternative to mysql-functions, for example mysqli. Mysql-functions are [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php).*

Comment: Oh wow. I really am that stupid. I guess I should get some sleep before I completely break everything.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$srv = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE `name` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']) . "%'");
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($srv)) {
    $playerInfo = array('id' => $playerarray['id'], 'name' => $playerarray['name'], 'server' => $playerarray['server']);
    echo(json_encode($playerInfo));
}
```

to this

```
$srv = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE `name` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']) . "%'");
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($srv)) {
    $playerInfo = array('id' => $record['id'], 'name' => $record['name'], 'server' => $record['server']);
    echo(json_encode($playerInfo));
}
```

Your variables name `$playerarray['id']` is wrong this is write `$record['id']`. Your data is in $record because of loop so you should use $record instead of `$playerarray`.